# ACF output not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a website but for some reason I can't get the custom fields to work. Im using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields and WP-Property.

So the WP-Property uses the page.php for a listing.

The page.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content-full-width">
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The Property-Overview.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Mark:
 * Aanbod template.
 * 
 * WP-Property Overview Template
 *
 * To customize this file, copy it into your theme directory, and the plugin will
 * automatically load your version.
 *
 * You can also customize it based on property type.  For example, to create a custom
 * overview page for 'building' property type, create a file called property-overview-building.php
 * into your theme directory.
 *
 *
 * Settings passed via shortcode:
 * $properties: either array of properties or false
 * $show_children: default true
 * $thumbnail_size: slug of thumbnail to use for overview page
 * $thumbnail_sizes: array of image dimensions for the thumbnail_size type
 * $fancybox_preview: default loaded from configuration
 * $child_properties_title: default "Floor plans at location:"
 *
 *
 *
 * @version 1.4
 * @author Andy Potanin <andy.potnain@twincitiestech.com>
 * @package WP-Property
*/?>
<?php
 if ( have_properties() ) {
   $thumbnail_dimentions = WPP_F::get_image_dimensions($wpp_query['thumbnail_size']);
?>
 <div class="<?php wpp_css('property_overview::row_view', "wpp_row_view wpp_property_view_result"); ?>">
  <div class="<?php wpp_css('property_overview::all_properties', "all-properties"); ?>">
  <?php foreach ( returned_properties('load_gallery=false') as $property) { 
    $isVerkochtVerhuurd = isset($property['verkocht_of_verhuurd']);
    $isHuur = $property["property_type"] == 'huurwoning' || $property["property_type"] == 'kamer';
    $isKoop = $property["property_type"] == 'koopwoning';
    ?>

    <div class="objectEntry">

        <div class="<?php wpp_css('property_overview::left_column', "wpp_overview_left_column"); ?>" style="">

    <div class="imgin">
          <?php property_overview_image(); ?>
    <div class="info-over-image">
        <?php the_field('flash', get_the_ID()); ?>
    </div>
    </div>

        </div>

        <div class="<?php wpp_css('property_overview::right_column', "wpp_overview_right_column"); ?>" style="">

            <ul class="<?php wpp_css('property_overview::data', "wpp_overview_data"); ?>">
                <li class="property_title">
                    <a <?php echo $in_new_window; ?> href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $property['post_title']; ?></a>
                    <?php if( !empty( $property['is_child'] ) ): ?>
                        <?php _e('of',ud_get_wp_property()->domain); ?> <a <?php echo $in_new_window; ?> href='<?php echo $property['parent_link']; ?>'><?php echo $property['parent_title']; ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>

            <?php if( !empty( $property['display_address'] ) ): ?>
                <li class="property_address"><a href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>#property_map"><?php echo $property['display_address']; ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

              <li class="kenmerkenContainer">
                 <ul class="kenmerken">
                    <?php if( !empty( $property['slaapkamers'] ) ): ?>
                        <li class="property_slaapkamers">
                            <span class="attribute"></span>
                            <span class="value"><?php echo $property['slaapkamers']; ?></span>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( !empty( $property['badkamer'] ) ): ?>
                        <li class="property_badkamers">
                            <span class="attribute"></span>
                            <span class="value"><i class="fas fa-shower"></i> <?php echo $property['badkamer']; ?></span>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( !empty( $property['area'] ) ): ?>
                        <li class="property_oppervlakte">
                            <span class="attribute">Oppervlakte:</span>
                            <span class="value"><?php echo $property['area']; ?></span>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if( !empty( $property['woning_type'] ) ): ?>
<!--                        <li class="property_oppervlakte"> -->
<!--                            <span class="attribute">Woningtype:</span> -->
                            <span class="value"><?php echo $property['woning_type']; ?></span>
<!--                        </li> -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </li>


                <li class="property_price"><div><?php echo $property['price']; ?></div></li>


    <li class="btn-view"><a class="knpweergeven" href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>">Bekijken</a></li>

            <?php if( $show_children && !empty( $property['children'] ) ): ?>
            <li class="child_properties">
                <div class="wpd_floorplans_title"><?php echo $child_properties_title; ?></div>
                <table class="wpp_overview_child_properties_table">
                    <?php foreach($property['children'] as $child): ?>
                    <tr class="property_child_row">
                        <th class="property_child_title"><a href="<?php echo $child['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $child['post_title']; ?></a></th>
                        <td class="property_child_price"><?php echo isset( $child['price'] ) ? $child['price'] : ''; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(!empty($wpp_query['detail_button'])) : ?>
            <li class="detailButton"><a <?php echo $in_new_window; ?> class="button" href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $wpp_query['detail_button'] ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
       </ul>

        </div><?php // .wpp_right_column ?>

    </div><?php // .property_div ?>

    <?php } /** end of the propertyloop. */ ?>
    </div><?php // .all-properties ?>
    </div><?php // .wpp_row_view ?>
<?php } else {  ?>
<div class="wpp_nothing_found">
   <p><?php echo sprintf(__('Geen woningen gevonden. Klik <a href="%s">hier</a> om al het aanbod te tonen.',ud_get_wp_property()->domain), site_url().'/'.$wp_properties['configuration']['base_slug']); ?></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see I'm using the follow code to retrieve the data from the custom field:

```
<div class="info-over-image">
    <?php the_field('flash', get_the_ID()); ?>
</div>
```

The output is not showing. I can't find what I'm doing wrong. The original code is:

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no any need for using Advanced custom fields with WP-Property plugin. WP-Property allows to create as many custom fields as you need and has different attributes fields inputs such as: Text Editor, Dropdown Selection, Single Checkbox, Multi-checkbox, Radio, Number, Currency, Oembed, File and Image Upload, URL, Date and Color Pickers, etc.

Also, WP-Property uses property.php template for single listings.

Regards.
Maria

Comment: Hi @Maria that's right. But I use ACF fore some other things as well. I'm also like the way how I easy can create my own shortcodes using ACF. The issue is not about the single page, where it works but about the listing page.

Comment: Here is tutorial how can you add wp-property attributes in to different templates - https://www.usabilitydynamics.com/product/wp-property/docs/customizing-templates-in-wp-property